# Assigning Code to a specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have three forms on a page with submit buttons in each, there is a code which is suppose to changes the value of a button in a particular form when clicked but when i click on that submit button all the values in the various forms buttons changes, but i want to change the value based on the form i click

```
<script language="javascript">
/**
 * Disable submit button
 */
$(function(){
      $('input:submit').click(function(){
            $(this).val('Request Placed...');
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
      });
});
$(window).load(function(){
      $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');
});
</script>
```

Comment: the code shown will only change the button clicked and not any other buttons. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. Logic used for `disabled` makes no sense either

Comment: did you try to replace $(window).load to $(document).ready ?

Comment: @qwertmax, i'm new to jquery so i don't know how to go about it. can you put it in a code form for me

Comment: @charlietfl, when i click on a submit button in a different form, the value of the button of that form also changes.

Comment: I think you need to provide a better explanation of exactly what is expected. Wording in question doesn't match what you are saying in comments. If you only want one button to do this, target it through a more specific selector. Giving it an ID is simplest selector, but could be based on parent form also

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? My speculative sample seems to work as expected...  http://jsfiddle.net/sP2Zv/1/

Comment: @DaveSalomon, just visited and saw what you did at jsfiddle, this is what is happening when my forms. but for example i want it to work for only form1 and not form2 and form3. do you get my point now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your requirements. However, this demo might give you some ideas to resolve your issues.

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="action1">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form id="form2" action="action2">
    <input type="text" id="txt2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form id="form3" action="action3">
    <input type="text" id="txt3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var $submitBtn,
        $form,
        submitBtnHandler = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.val('Request Placed...');
            $self.prop('disabled', true);
            $self.parents('form').submit();
        },
        formSubmitHandler = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Added this to stay in the same page when submit form. If you want to redirect to the action URL(action1, action2, action3 etc), please remove it.
            alert("Hi, I am " + this.id);
        },
        resetSubmitBtnState = function () {
            $submitBtn.removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        init = function () {
            $submitBtn = $('input:submit');
            $form = $('form');

            $submitBtn.on('click', submitBtnHandler);
            $form.on('submit', formSubmitHandler);
        };
    $(document).ready(init);
    $(window).load(resetSubmitBtnState);
}());
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w3devjs/3Byb2/

Comment: No need to @reply here; the OP always gets notified when an answer is posted to his question.

Comment: rob your code worked perfectly but the problem one of the form is assign an action where has to take a variable to a different page but it seems not to redirect to the page. When i enter some variables in the textfield and i press on send, the button disables and come with an alert, but i want it to be able to send the variable to a different page, while the  other forms others are disable on click. there are three forms, first to be be disabled on click and the other to send variable on click. i hope u get me this time

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery selector to select only form that you need, only input from form with `id="form_2"` will be supported

```
$(function(){
      $('input:submit', '#form_2').click(function(){
            $(this).val('Request Placed...');
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/sP2Zv/2/

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you could do this,
`document.getElementById("BUTTON'S ID").value = "TEXT HERE";`
Just make that line an `onclick` one.

So, when the user clicks the button, an `onclick` event happens, that will change the button's vaule. Be sure that in the `input` tag, there is an `id` for the button as well as a `value` for it.

So, here's a little example I whipped up,

In HTML,

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="Input" />
    <input type="button" id="BUTTON'S ID" value="TEXT HERE" onclick="Changetxt()" />
</form>
```

In JavaScript,

```
<script>
    function Changetxt()
    {
        document.getElementById("BUTTON'S ID").value = "SOME OTHER TEXT";
    }
</script>
```

So, when the user clicks the button, the button's text changes from `TEXT HERE` to `SOME OTHER TEXT`.